# cURL returns 404 but browser 200 ok

Tags: php, curl

I try to get html page content from a page on a remote server. But when I use cURL via a php script or on the command line from the server (Debian), a 404 error is returned for any url of the remote server. But if I paste this url on my browser, it returns the page correctly with all content... Why?... :-(
Example of url : https://www.neptunestore.eu/fra/neptune-systems-module-de-surveillance-des-fluides.html

Comment: You should add some code. No-one has any idea of what you're doing and why it isn't working.

Comment: Is that the url you are attempting to call with curl? If so it is returning a 404 response. Without any code we can't help you.

Comment: please add your curl request. so that everyone can take a look

Comment: The URL you mentioned does not work for me the first time either. When I find the corresponding product on the English version of the site however, and then use the language switcher to go to the French version, it does … So this site probably relies on some cookies or something that must be present, for it to return the content correctly.

Comment: Nevermind the code, you can do a DOM with PHP, u cURL in php or in command lne with or wothout options, useragent etc it is the same problem! Just do a curl -i http://wwwxxxxxxx and you'll se the problem.
But you're right : it doesn't do the problem with the english version!!

Answer (score 0):

I receive 404 in browser with this message `There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.`.
It seems to something wrong with this page.

Comment: Yes, seems to be only the french version that have this problem!